# Combine Image and Text to print them

Tags: android, zxing

I want to create an .png to print it. The file should have this layout (100x35mm)
[image]

I created the QrCode using the Zxing project.

```
 public Bitmap createQrCode(String stringForQrCode){
    com.google.zxing. MultiFormatWriter writer =new MultiFormatWriter();

    String data = stringForQrCode;
    String finaldata = Uri.encode(data, "utf-8");

    BitMatrix bm = null;
    try {
        bm = writer.encode(finaldata, BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE,185, 185);
    } catch (WriterException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap ImageBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(185, 185, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    for (int i = 0; i < 185; i++) {//width
        for (int j = 0; j < 185; j++) {//height
            assert bm != null;
            ImageBitmap.setPixel(i, j, bm.get(i, j) ? Color.BLACK: Color.WHITE);
        }
    }
    return ImageBitmap;
}
```

But how can I combine these image with my two Strings. Do I have to create an new bitmap? And How to I chose the position of the different Items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it by creating an bitmap from the desired View. Therefore I create a View which includes my qrcode and both strings. But instead of displaying the View, I set it on `invisible` and use the following code to create and save the bitmap.

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromView(View view, int width, int height) {
        Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
        Drawable bgDrawable =view.getBackground();
        if (bgDrawable!=null) {
            bgDrawable.draw(canvas);
        } else {
            canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
        }
        view.draw(canvas);
        return returnedBitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

first you create the bitmap of both image and text parent view

```
public static Bitmap loadBitmapFromView(View v) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap( v.getLayoutParams().width, v.getLayoutParams().height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);                
    Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
    v.layout(v.getLeft(), v.getTop(), v.getRight(), v.getBottom());
    v.draw(c);
    return b;
}
```

now convert this bitmap to any format as you want